# how to check if cart has already added not allow more and update if different cart

Tags: laravel

I'm using composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart I am not sure how to maintain amount.

When i'm using one route that says add item when i'm using this route adding multiple item

How can i conditionally setup to add item in cart if this is unique

```
public function bookItem($id) {
      $item = Item::where([
        'status' => '1',
        'id' => $id
      ])->first();


      $product = Cart::add($item->id, $item->name, 1, $item->price); // This should not call always if it has not generated a row id then  it should call

     Cart::update($product->rowId, ['price' => 200]); // Will update the price if it is differ

      return redirect()->route('book.item', ['id' => $item->id]);

    }
```

I am not sure how to manage it. please guide

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package has a getContents() function that gathers all items into a collection.  It also has a search(Closure) function that calls getContents() and then uses Laravel's filter function on the collection and returns the result.

```
$search = Cart::search(function($key,$value) use ($item) {
    return $value === $item->id;
})->first();

if(!empty($search)){
    Cart::update($search->rowId, ['price' => 200]);
}
else {
    $product = Cart::add($item->id, $item->name, 1, $item->price);
}
```

Definitely check out the Laravel collection docs if you aren't familiar.  This is the entey on filters:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter